# Can I use AWS FIFO Queue with AWS SNS Standard Topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, fifo, aws-sqs-fifo

Looking at the SNS & SQS documentation, I couldn't find a specific article that mentioned this combination.

Physically I found it's possible to create a subscription of a FIFO queue to a Standard Topic. However, in the AWS console for SQS FIFO queue, under SNS subscriptions it's always empty.

It does seem as if you can publish a message and it will arrive at the lambda triggered via the FIFO queue, but is message ordering/grouping basically discarded? Like what is the point of using this combination? Ideally you want to use FIFO topic + FIFO Queue?

Comment: "it's possible to create a subscription of a FIFO queue to a Standard Topic" - how exactly did you do that? Can you share your procedure, screenshots? I think you must be misinterpreting something.

Comment: In what way are you wanting to combine an Amazon SQS queue with an Amazon SNS topic? What is your use-case?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What I found out was that you need a FIFO Topic to ensure strict ordering of insertion into a FIFO queue, but that you still get message grouping on a FIFO queue regardless of whether the message came from Standard/FIFO topic